# How to get value of a given key if found in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to get the value of a given key if found using the `array_key_exists` function.

```
$var = 35;

if(array_key_exists($var, $_SESSION['cart_items']))
{
    //give the value of found key
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$var] = $anothervar;
}
```

For now, I only have this:

```
Array
(
    [35] => 3
    [41] => 6
)
```

So what I wanted to get is the value `3`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quite understand, but I assume your $_SESSION['cart_items'] is:

```
Array
(
    [35] => 3
    [41] => 6
)
```

Then, to get value 3, all you need is:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][$var]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable itself in the array declaration.  Just put it between the [] brackets.  Such as below.  If you echo $the_value after that statement it should be 3.

```
if(array_key_exists($var, $_SESSION['cart_items'])) {
    $the_value = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$var];
}
else {
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$var] = $anothervar;
}
```